# YaBrowser в HTTP USER AGENT

Tags: php

Вообщем такая проблема, есть код:

```
$user_agent = $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"];
if (strpos($user_agent, "Firefox") !== false) $browser = "Firefox";
elseif (strpos($user_agent, "Opera") !== false) $browser = "Opera";
elseif (strpos($user_agent, "Chrome") !== false) $browser = "Chrome";
elseif (strpos($user_agent, "MSIE") !== false) $browser = "Internet Explorer";
elseif (strpos($user_agent, "Safari") !== false) $browser = "Safari";
elseif (strpos($user_agent, "YaBrowser") !== false) $browser = "Yandex Browser";
else $browser = "Неизвестный";
```

Но проблема в том что если заходить с Yandex Браузера то выдаёт Chrome, как можно определить Yandex по другому?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмортите на то, как устроен `User Agent` у Yandex-браузера. Устроен он, например, так:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.12785 YaBrowser/13.12.1599.12785 Safari/537.36
```

Не сложно увидеть, что в ней и правда есть подстрока `Chrome` соответственно Chrome и будет выдан в качестве браузера.
  Самый простой способ этого избежать это сначала (раньше Chrome) проверять, есть ли подстрока `YaBrowser`.